# Scala: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider

Tags: jersey-2.0

I have the following piece of code to make a call to receive a token and i am getting the jersey error.Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider i am not able to figure out why. I have given the pom as well.. Can anyone suggest whats the issue.?

```
  import javax.ws.rs.client.{ClientBuilder, Entity}             
  import javax.ws.rs.core.{MediaType, Response}                          
  import com.google.gson.JsonParser
  import com.rms.execution._             
  import com.rms.transform.constants.ApiConstants             
  import com.rms.transform.constants.ImportPayloadSettingParameters._
  import com.rms.transform.task.api.TaskConstants
  import com.rms.transform.task.api.TaskConstants._
  import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration             
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
  import org.json.{JSONException, JSONObject}
  import org.junit.runner.RunWith             
  import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
  import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfter, FunSuite}            
  import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}                          
  import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap             
  import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
  import scala.util.control.Breaks._

test("Do a datastore commit ) {           
    val jobId: Integer = 1                      
    val token: String = getToken
    }



    @throws[JSONException]             
private def getToken : String = {               
        val body = HashMap("username" -> “a”,”tenant”->”b”,”password"->“c”)              
         var bearerToken : String = ""               
        val client = ClientBuilder.newClient               
        val response = client.target(“http://”).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(body))              
        if (response != null){               
        val tokenResponse = response.readEntity(classOf[String])                
        val json :JSONObject = new JSONObject(tokenResponse);                
        val token :String = json.get("token").toString();                 
        bearerToken = "Bearer " + token             
       }                            
        bearerToken            
}

POM is below..

    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.ws.rs-api.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.rms</groupId>
                <artifactId>import-hdfs</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>uk.co.datumedge</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-json</artifactId>
                <version>${hamcrest-json.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.rms</groupId>
                <artifactId>execution-common</artifactId>
                <version>${jobs.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
                <version>${scalatest.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                <version>${scala.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Comment: Do you import the jersey library anywhere? The only place I see jersey dealt with at all is in the exclusions of your POM.

Comment: Nowhere.. I just have one dependency which is javax...

Comment: Wouldn't you need to import it? ClassDefNotFound errors are usually just a matter of a forgotten import (or an import not resolving for some reason).

Comment: Tried removing the exclusion even then it wouldnt work.

Comment: Yeah that wouldn't do anything related to importing. 

That file is in this package as far as I can see:

https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.19/jersey/com/sun/jersey/core/provider/jaxb/package-summary.html

Try to import the package/class and see what happens. I'm not sure this will fix your problem but it might give a hint.

Comment: Keep in mind you'll need the binary (the .jar) in order to import the class, just like any other imported lib you use. I found this:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjerseycorejar.htm